# deploying angular2 application in pcf

Tags: angular, deployment, pcf

I am trying to deploy my `angular2` application to `pivotal cloud foundry` and I followed the instructions found [here](https://spiegela.com/2015/08/10/angular-apps-in-cloud-foundry/) but I am keep getting `Loading...`, there are no errors found in developer console.

```
/d/gitmyworkspace/mywork/pcfdeploy/src
$ npm install --quite
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
/d/gitmyworkspace/mywork/pcfdeploy/src
$ cf push -b staticfile_buildpack ang-pcf-dep
Creating app ang-pcf-dep in org ORG / space development as myDetails...OK
Creating route ang-pcf-dep.domain.com... OK
Binding ang-pcf-dep.domain.com to ang-pcf-dep... OK
Uploading ang-pcf-dep...
Uploading app files from: D:\gitmyworkspace\mywork\pcfdeploy\src
Uploading 12.9K, 18 files Done uploading OK
Starting app ang-pcf-dep in org ORG / space development as myDetails...
Downloading staticfile_buildpack...Downloaded staticfile_buildpack
Creating container    Successfully created container  Downloading app package...
Downloaded app package (6.4K)   Staging...
-------> Buildpack version 1.3.6
Downloaded [file:///tmp/buildpacks/5d1fcb59173496506d68186968a7b83f/dependencies/https___pivotal-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com_concourse-binaries_nginx_nginx-1.9.14-linux-x64.tgz]
grep: Staticfile: No such file or directory
-----> Using root folder
-----> Copying project files into public/
-----> Setting up nginx
grep: Staticfile: No such file or directory
grep: Staticfile: No such file or directory
Exit status 0
Staging complete
Uploading droplet, build artifacts cache...
Uploading build artifacts cache...
Uploading droplet...
Uploaded build artifacts cache (107B)
Uploaded droplet (2.5M)
Uploading complete
1 of 1 instances running
App started  OK
App ang-pcf-dep was started using this command `sh boot.sh`
Showing health and status for app ang-pcf-dep in org ORG /spacedevelopment as myDetails ... OK
requested state: started
instances: 1/1
usage: 1G x 1 instances
urls: ang-pcf-dep.domain.com
last uploaded: Thu Mar 9 18:53:22 UTC 2017
stack: cflinuxfs2
buildpack: staticfile_buildpack
state     since                    cpu    memory       disk         details
#0   running   2017-03-09 10:53:34 AM   0.0%   3.2M of 1G   6.9M of 1G
```

In browser it is just loading the `index.html` but not the other components like `app.component.html`. I just created a basic application using webstorm `AngularCli` and `node 6.9.5` to test the `pcf deployment`. Please let me know if I missed anything?

Answer (score 7):

For `AngularCli` we suppose to do below steps ...

```
$ng build
$ cd dist
$ cf push -b staticfile_buildpack ang-pcf-dep
```

please note for `AngularCli` you should push from `dist` folder not `app` or `src` folder and all resource files like images should be in `assets` folder. Thanks to `Rob` from pcf.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create a manifest file (.yml)

cf push -f manifest-xxx-dev(qa).yml -b staticfile_buildpack

This will help to maintain environments, and domain changes and all will be easier.

Sample Manifest file (save as manifest-dev(qa).yml)

---

applications:
- name: {Application}
  memory: 1024MB
  instances: 1
  host: {environmentFriendlyName}
  domains:
  - {domainName}
  timeout: 600